# MySQL への接続でエラー - ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

Tags: mysql

AWS Lightsail への MySQL 導入後、まず MySQL にログインしようとしましたが、以下のエラーが出てきます。

```
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
Unable to connect to the server as root user, giving up.
Cleaning up...
```

mysql.sockが無いとのことなので、作成しました。

```
$ sudo touch /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

すると、今度はエラーの番号が変わり、パーミッションが無いとのメッセージです。

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)
```

なので、パーミッションを与えます。

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

そうすると、今度はさらにサーバーへ接続できないというエラーが出ます。

```
$ mysql -u root
: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
```

同時に、はじめに作成したファイル　/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock　を削除しろとのメッセージが、

```
$ sudo service mysqld start
Socket file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists.
The file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock is not a socket file, which is suspicious.
Please, remove /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock manually to start the service.
```

削除します。

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

すると、また振り出しに戻ります。

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

my.cnf ファイルには下記を記載しています。

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0
character-set-server=utf8
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M

[client]
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port        = 3306

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
```

logはこのようになっております。

```
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2020-08-23 09:25:26 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: "削除します" で実行したコマンドの部分に `sudo` が二回出てきており、二つのコマンドが1行にくっついて見えますが、本当にコマンドはこの通り実行したのでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼いたしました。2回目のsudoはこちらへの記載ミスでございましたので修正いたしました。

Answer (score 2):

`mysql` コマンドと `mysqld` コマンドの違いは理解していますか？　何か無駄なことをやっているようにしか見えないのですが

`mysqld` つまり MySQL デーモン本体が起動するときに `mysqld` が `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` という**ソケット**を作成する仕様です。そして `mysql` コマンドはこのソケットに接続しようとします。なのであなたが `sudo touch /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` などと**通常ファイル**を作ってしまうと当然ソケットへの接続が失敗してエラーになります。なのでファイルを削除しろと言ってくるのは当然の結果で以下ループ。

`mysql.sock` に接続できない = `mysql.sock` ソケットを `mysqld` が生成していない = `mysqld` が起動失敗している、と推定出来て、よって今見るべきは `log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log` で指定したエラーログファイルということになります。

---

別質問があったのね。ログも転載されてきたので読んでみます。致命傷となっているのは

> `2020-08-23 09:25:27 4206 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode`

`InnoDB:  ./ibdata1 が読み書き可能モードで開けません。`

理由を妄想してみるに

- ユーザ `mysql` グループ `mysql` が無い / 無効化されている / 権限設定が不良でうまく機能しない
- `MYSQL_DATADIR` が無い / 設定不良
- `MYSQL_DATADIR` 以下に `ibdata1` ファイルが無い
- `MYSQL_DATADIR` にユーザー/グループ `mysql` の読み書き権限が無い
- `ibdata1` ファイルにユーザ/グループ `mysql` の読み書き権限が無い
- `MYSQL_DATADIR` 以下の容量が足らなかったなどの理由で `ibdata1` が壊れている
- なんか知らないファイルが勝手に増えていたので誰かが削除してしまった（人間とは限らずセキュリティソフトが検疫したとか）

妄想するだけならいくらでも広げられますが、真相がわかるのは質問者だけです。

ウチの hpux サーバちゃんには古い `mysql` が入っていて `MYSQL_DATADIR=/home/mysql/data` と指定しています。

```
# cd /home/mysql/data
# ls -l ibdata1
-rw-rw----    1 mysql    mysql     45651584 Aug  5  16:38 ibdata1
#
```

のようにユーザ `mysql` グループ `mysql` で `ibdata1` が読み書き可能となっていて、正しく `mysqld` が起動しています。

Comment: 質問者本人による重複質問にログファイルの内容が記載されていたので、こちらの質問に転記しておきました。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。  
ご教示いただきましたいくつかの理由について確認いたします。  

一度下記コマンドでファイルを削除したことも原因の一つだとおもいます。  

`
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql/*
`

Comment: うーんそれは俗にいう「何もしてないのに壊れた（いっぱい余計なことをしていて何をしたかは覚えていない）」ってやつですね。そもそも LightSail の OS は何で MySQL をどうやって導入しましたか？　たぶん今の状況は触りたおした結果いろいろなものが不明な形で壊れているので MySQL の削除→再インストールのほうが手早そうです。

Comment: @net-pixel `/var/lib/mysql/` 以下には設定ファイルで指定しているようにデータベースファイルも含まれているので、ディレクトリ自体を削除するのは間違いです (手動で作成したファイルだけを個別に削除すべき) / エラーログにも「データベースが開けない」と出ているのこれが原因じゃないでしょうか。改めてデータベースを作り直すか、774RR さんのアドバイス通り、いったん MySQL を再インストールするのも一つの方法だと思います。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます！
おっしゃる通りいろいろ知識がない状態で実行しておりました。
ディレクトリを削除してしまったことも大きな原因だと認識いたしました。
再度確認しつつ
一度再インストール試してみます。

Comment: 一度アンインストールし、無事インストールすることができました。
ご教示ありがとうございました。